# Lower level than NSCursor

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cursor

I'm trying to set the cursor when the mouse goes over a PDFView.  I have overridden `(void)resetCursorRects` but it only changes the cursor when the pointer is between the edge of the view and the content of the pdf, then the PDFView sets it back to text selection when over the content.  Is there a lower level way to set the current cursor?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, found the answer: `- (void)setCursorForAreaOfInterest:(PDFAreaOfInterest)area`